# Postgres: How to count records with conditions CONSECUTIVELY in a certain period of time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have a table with the following columns:

- (PK)sales_log_id
- user_id
- created_at

```
sales_log_id | user_id | created_at
-------------|---------|------------
0001         | aaa     | 2019-06-01
0002         | aaa     | 2019-06-01
0003         | aaa     | 2019-06-01
0004         | aaa     | 2019-06-01
0005         | bbb     | 2019-06-01
0006         | bbb     | 2019-06-01
0007         | aaa     | 2019-06-02
0008         | aaa     | 2019-06-02
0009         | aaa     | 2019-06-02
0010         | aaa     | 2019-06-02
0011         | bbb     | 2019-06-02
0012         | ccc     | 2019-06-02
0013         | ccc     | 2019-06-02
0014         | ccc     | 2019-06-02
0015         | ccc     | 2019-06-02
0016         | ddd     | 2019-06-02
0017         | ddd     | 2019-06-02
```

And the output I'm looking for is:

```
user_id | count
--------|------
aaa     | 2
```

or just as simple as

```
1
```

since only aaa have >=4 sales_log_id consecutively per day since the beginning of **WHERE period 2019-06-01 to 2019-06-02**.

I need to do count on users that have eg. >= 4 transactions **consecutively** (represents with sales_log_id) IN a day for certain period of time - let say last month.

I have been able to count users that have >= 4 transaction per month only.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, COUNT (user_id) 
FROM sales_log 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30' 
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING COUNT (sales_log_id) >= 4;
```

Can someone give me an example of doing this with a subquery?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `distinct` is completely useless

Comment: What about the part where "have >= 4 transactions in a day" for the month? @S-Man

Comment: Absolutely useless, will remove it later, thanks for pointing @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: It's a bit unclear what result you expect. Can you please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: Why not `ccc` for `2019-06-02`?

Comment: `ccc` doesn't have record in `2019-06-01`. If the query is for `2019-06-02` then `ccc` is counted for. @forpas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `GROUP BY user_id, created_at` to get the users with at least 4 transactions in 1 day and then `GROUP BY user_id` on the results and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT t.user_id, COUNT(t.created_at) counter
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, created_at
  FROM sales_log 
  WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-02' 
  GROUP BY user_id, created_at  
  HAVING COUNT(sales_log_id) >= 4
) t
GROUP BY t.user_id
HAVING COUNT(t.created_at) = 1 + '2019-06-02'::date - '2019-06-01'::date
```

or:

```
SELECT count(distinct t.user_id) usercounter
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, created_at
  FROM sales_log 
  WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-02' 
  GROUP BY user_id, created_at  
  HAVING COUNT(sales_log_id) >= 4
) t
GROUP BY t.user_id
HAVING COUNT(t.created_at) = 1 + '2019-06-02'::date - '2019-06-01'::date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=6ed16424ea6480a6a5cae86115ee97cd).
Results:

```
> user_id | counter
> :------ | ------:
> aaa     |       2
```

and

```
> | usercounter |
> | ----------: |
> |           1 |
```

Comment: Just created absolutely the same query :D https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5e7c4f808c5c3a917c6897efb0510113

Comment: You did? I'm trying for a fiddle for 10 mins and got tired of copy and paste.....

Comment: My secret: Copy the table into SQL fiddle -> Text To DDL function ;)

Comment: This absolutely fits the bill for me! Thanks forpas and @S-Man thank you for pointing a cool tool dbfiddle. I have some more questions on this. Should I open a new question? It's kinda related.

Comment: @Worka Yes, please open a new question